# Add label on top of two textarea [CSS]

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner on CSS.

I want to add a label on the top of the two textarea. When I tried Label tag (as shown below) , the second textarea ends up beeing under the first textarea( basically I want them side by side ).

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/agr3a07m/199/)

```html
<label for="Coords">Past Coordinates here: </label>    
<textarea id="Coords" cols="35" rows="20"></textarea>
<label for="Time">Time: </label>
<textarea id="Time" cols="25" rows="20"></textarea>
```

My two textarea are wrapped to put them on the right.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks!

Comment: try this`label{ display:block}`

Comment: what problem is ther in  your jsfiddle example

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sherali/agr3a07m/203/

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Thanks for your reply. Actually I want them on the right of the page. How can I have this ?

Comment: only labels or both?

Comment: They *are* on the right.

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev I want something like http://fiddle.jshell.net/agr3a07m/196/show/ with label on top of each Textarea

Comment: @H.Tirit.  is it http://fiddle.jshell.net/sherali/agr3a07m/208/ ?

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Yes ! Thank you !

Comment: I updated my answer. Also, you can do upvote. :). it has optimized.

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev It is done !

Comment: @H.Tirit. you have accepted, you can do upvote too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this. http://fiddle.jshell.net/sherali/agr3a07m/209/show/
UPDATED:

Tip: remove your `cols` and `rows` from textarea. you  should define from css(thorugh `width`, `height`)

in HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <label for="Coords">Title of Coords: </label>
    <textarea id="Coords"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <label for="Time">Title of Time: </label>
    <textarea id="Time"></textarea>
</div>
```

in CSS:

```
textarea#Coords{
    width:270px;
    height:300px;
}

textarea#Time{
    width:215px;
    height:300px;
}
label {display:block;}
.box{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to wrap each label/textarea pair in a div and set `display: inline-block;` on each div. Though I'd recommend checking out some frameworks with grid systems, like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), that abstract and simplify this.